# Google Play shows the older APK version files

Tags: google-play

I uploaded a new apk with a new version name and code on the developer console. It is showing activated. But google play is still showing the old version. It has been 20 mins since i updated the apk.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple apks for the same application, you should remove all the previous ones and only keep the newest

Comment: i have deactived them, how to remove them? Sorry, im a newbie that's why the silly questions